# Sqlserver query to display rowwise

Tags: sql-server

I have data like below,

```
Item#       Cust         Type
C1          AAA            1
C1          BBB            2
C1          CCC            2

C2          DDD            2
C2          EEE            2
C2          FFF            2
```

> I want to display rowwise based on Item# For eg.,

```
Item#     Type1        Type2
C1        AAA          BBB
C1                     CCC
C2                     DDD
C2                     EEE
C2                     FFF
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `PIVOT` operator. However you have multiple `Cust` for the same `Type`, in order to display all, you will need to differenciate it with a `row_number()`

```
select  Item#, [1] as Type1, [2] as Type2
from    (
            select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Item#, Type order by Cust)
            from    yourtable
        ) t
        pivot
        (
            max(Cust)
            for Type in ([1], [2])
        ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Item#
    ,[1] AS Type1
    ,[2] AS Type2
FROM (SELECT * FROM yourtable) tbl
PIVOT (MAX(Cust)
       FOR [Type] IN ([1], [2])
      ) pvttable